# AngularFire in Ionic - I can't get proper data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to make a mobile app and use ionic.

I coded controller section, app section and configured Firebase database.

But code doesn't work properly.

The problem is that when i run $firebaseArray function it returns me not an array of datas but an array of functions and a complicated version of data.

Here what it returns:

http://pasteboard.co/9on5uyy6T.png

Here is my files:
  --controller js---

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ["firebase"])
.controller('whatAreYouGonnaDoCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$firebaseArray','$firebaseObject',
function ($scope, $stateParams,$firebaseArray,$firebaseObject) {

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var subRef = rootRef.child("todos");
  var takenval = $firebaseArray(subRef);

  $scope.addtodo = function(){
    console.log(takenval);
  };

}])
```

-- app js---

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services',"firebase"])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Just a pointer, I guess the website says it's deprecated. Did you get a chance to see that?

Comment: That looks like a $firebaseArray instance, yes. It's also an array you can iterate. It also works wonderfully with ng-repeat. So what's the problem?